# How do I make a Mojang account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I go to create a Mojang account, it just takes me to the Minecraft website and does not give me an option to make a Mojang account, only makes me sign into my Microsoft. On a lot of server clients, it gives you the option to log into your Mojang account, and I have seen people register on YouTube but don't know how. What do I do???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mojang accounts [are being phased out soon](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360050865492-JAVA-Account-Migration-FAQ) in favor of Microsoft accounts. There is no way to create a new Mojang account. Even if you could create a new Mojang account, you would need to migrate it to a Microsoft account soon anyway.

Comment: More info on their official blog here https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/java-edition-moving-house

Comment: @Noob2ProPlayz If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted, so that everyone knows the problem is now solved.

Comment: Mojang is being very reckless in this migration, they should have provided a Microsoft account based solution for all legitimate customers before retiring the creation of Mojang accounts. Anyone running the Java edition on a non-standard platform (like Raspberry Pi) has to use the Java launcher, whose latest version (1.6.93) still only supports Mojang accounts. The first part of this answer is factually true, but "you would need to migrate anyway" is off-topic.